# Intercepting ADD to detect if it is an ADD through a collection in Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have kinda 2 questions that can be answered separately.

**Q#1**

I am trying to save round trips to the database server.

Here's my algo:

1. Insert 2 entities (to get their IDs generated by the database)
2. Use the IDs returned to call a stored procedure passing it the IDs

The stored procedure takes the IDs and populates an adjacency list table which I am using to store a directed acyclic graph.

Currently I have a round-trip to the RDBMS for each parent-child relationship, plus one for the Insert of the entities.

I am known to do stuff like this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added).ToList())
    {
        if (entry.Entity is IRobot)
        {
            entry.Reference("Owner").CurrentValue = skyNet;
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

So I was wondering if there was a way that I can detect an **EntityState.Added** for an "ADD" that was done similar to the following code:

```
var robot = new Robot(); 
skyNet.Robots.Add(robot); 
db.Add(skyNet); 
db.SaveChanges();
```

So that I can do something like this: (Note that this is psuedocode)

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.**AddedToCollection**).ToList())
    {
        db.Relate(parent: skyNet, child: entry.Entity);
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Q#2**

Is there anyway to call a stored procedure as part of the same "trip" to the database after calling a SaveChanges()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Question 1**

You can detect the state of an entity by

```cs
db.Entry(robot).State
```

After the line

```cs
skyNet.Robots.Add(robot);
```

the `EntityState` of `robot` will be `Added`. However, in your pseudocode it is not clear where the `skyNet` variable comes from. If you add the `skyNet` as you do in your code snippet you could do:

```cs
foreach( var skyNet in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                    .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added)
                                    .Select (e => e.Entity)
                                    .OfType<SkyNet>())
{
    foreach(var robot in skyNet.Robots
                             .Where(r => db.Entry(r).State == EntityState.Added))
    {
        db.Relate(parent: skyNet, child: robot);
    }
}
```

### **Question 2**

You can't call a stored procedure in one roundtrip, that would require something like NHibernate's multi query. But, you can wrap `SaveChanges` and a stored procedure call in one transaction (which I think is what you mean) by using [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx):

```cs
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // stored procedure call here.
    db.SaveChanges();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Q1: It looks like I could extend your answer to be generic (because I do not know if I have skyNets or robots), I just know that all objects which implement the IRobot interface need to be related in a parent-child type of relationship.  I'm thinking... Loop through each added entries properties and test for ICollection<IRobot> recursively and for each IRobot that has been added call Relate.

Comment: Q2: I was actually thinking communication round trips, not transaction.  My database is located on another continent so minimizing round trips helps my performance a lot.  I think I might look into extending EF to support NHibernate's multi-query.  I don't personally see a technical roadblock as to of why it isn't implemented.  +1 to you anyways.

Comment: Sounds good (twice)! Take the challenge. You could even contribute to EF's open source (as version 6).